# How to use CD40109BE to level shift one input from 3v to 5v?

Tags: raspberry-pi, level-shifting, character-lcd

I want to use the Raspberry Pi's 3.3v GPIO pins to control whether a 5v LCD screen is on or off. The Raspberry Pi has a 5v pin but it cannot be turned on or off using Python or similar. Only the 3.3v GPIO pins can.

Therefore, to do this I want to use a CD40109BE level shifter ([datasheet](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/cd40109b.pdf)) to shift the GPIO pin's voltage from 3.3v to 5v but I'm not quite sure how to connect it up.

Here's a schematic of what I *want* to do with the chip:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fZOUQc.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

But how would I do it? What pins and components would I need to use? I tried the schematic from [this answer](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/236451/how-to-connect-a-cd40109be-voltage-level-shifter) but it didn't seem to work for me and I only want to use a single input and output.

Thank you

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE, Billy. You need to include a datasheet link for the LCD so we know what type of input it has. Please edit your post to include it there.

Comment: Hello, the LCD screen does not have a datasheet but here is a link to the product. http://amzn.eu/6OWDXoW

Comment: "I tried the schematic from this answer but it didn't seem to work" - that schematic should work if you put +3.3V on pin 1 and +5V on pin 16. Exactly how do you expect the output to turn the LCD on and off? (CD40109 output can only source ~0.5mA, so it could control a switch but can't supply power directly to the LCD).

Answer (score 1):

That is an [TC1602A-01T](https://cdn-shop.adafruit.com/datasheets/TC1602A-01T.pdf) display and the datasheet was found by searching for "1602 LCD datasheet".

The CD40109BE is designed for shifting logic-level signals. In your case you want to switch the backlight on and off. Reading the datasheet reveals:

[image]

*Figure 1. Datasheet extract. Note the warning!*

The CD40109BE is not suitable for switching 100 mA.

[image]

*Figure 2. R1 limits the current to a safe value. Q1 allows switching from a 3.3 V GPIO. Source: [1602 LCD backlight LED](http://lednique.com/display-technology/1602-lcd-backlight-led/).*

\$ R_1 = \frac {V_{SS}–4.1}{0.1 } \$

For a 5 V supply this would give R1 = 9 Ω. The nearest standard value is 10 Ω and this would be fine.

Comment: Thank you. This seems to be working except for the fact that when the LCD screen is off, it is ~3v when it should be 0v. 3v still shows the backlight. (nb: My R1 is 100Ω because I don't have any 10Ω resistors)

Comment: (1) "*... it is ~3v when it should be 0v.*" What is? Please reference the schematic. For example, "I measure 3 V between A and GND when the GPIO pin reads 0.2 V." (2) Put 3, 4 or 5 x 100 Ω resistors in parallel. \$ R = \frac {100}{n} \$ where *n* is the number of resistors. (3) What value is R2. (4) What transistor did you use?